# Access files in external storage from HAL of AOSP

Tags: android, android-source, hal

I need to access files present in external storage from HAL (in some cpp file) of AOSP.

Answer (score 0):

Hal layer define the hardware for framework layers in android system , if you want to have access external storage , first you should create a jni access in framework , second in java layer gain access to external storage and you can pass the result to your by jni interface to your Hal module